# Wordpress Media Library and Image Upload takes too long and gets stuck

Tags: php, wordpress, media

All sites hosted on same server started behaving like this without doing any changing/modification to the server.

When I try to upload an image to a WordPress site, it takes too long (5+ minutes) to upload and sometimes gets stuck.

When I try to open media library, the page does load and then a circle gets revolving again and again, it takes another 5-10 minutes to load the images.

The sites are hosted on Apache/Nginx dedicated server and I'm using latest version of WordPress.

Comment: screenshot: http://prntscr.com/6dktbc

Comment: How big are these images?

Comment: 200 KB to 2 MB, All was perfect few hours ago when suddenly this problem occurred. I think this is server side issue not wordpress issue as all sites hosted on this server are affected

Comment: You might try Server Fault if you don't think this is a Wordpress issue.  Can you checked the CPU use on the server?

Comment: Isn't there a dedicated stack exchange site for Wordpress?  This might be better asked there.

Comment: I've fixed up your post a bit, but as it is, it's not currently on-topic. You might want to try the WordPress.SE site or add some code.